# Declaring a 2D array using double pointer

Tags: c++

I am confused about this line in a C++ program. The idea of the program is to check whether a `4x4` array is symmetric or not. This part of the code declares a 2D array, which I do not understand.

```
int** array = new int*[n];
```

Although, there is another question similar to this but it is about single pointer which I get.

```
int *array = new int[n];
```

I do not understand the double pointer. Kindly explain.

Comment: Think of it this way: The first of those is allocating a sequence of `n` pointers each of which can then be assigned something akin to the second line, which you already understand. You then access the i'th "row" of data via `array[i]`. But that is just an `int*`. You can therefore access *its* j'th "column" of data via `array[i][j]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you create a single pointer array? You do this:

```
int* myArray = new int[n];
```

What does this mean? It has two parts. First part is reserving a pointer `int*` we call it `myArray`, and the second part is that you reserve `n` elements, each with size `int` in memory (this is an array, right?), and you take the address of that array and you save it in the variable `myArray`.

Now you want a 2D array, which is an array of an array. So Every element of this new array of array is one of these, that we talked about up there. How do we reserve this? We do:

```
new int*[n];
```

Because we are reserving `n` slots, each with type `int*`, that we talked about before.

Now what is the type of the return value? It's an array of an array, or a "pointer to an array, and the latter is also a pointer to an array", so you write it as

```
(int*)*
```

Or

```
int**
```

so it becomes

```
int** array = new int*[n];
```

Comment: "...a 2D array, which is an array of an array" - that statement is accurate. But the OP's confusion need not be furthered by confusing an array of *arrays* with an array of *pointers*. They're **not** synonymous. The latter proffers syntactic sugar to look like the former, but they're in no way the same. I hope the OP grasps this or they'll be back posting another question about why passing `a`, declared as `int a[n][m];` to a function expecting `int **ar` doesn't work.

Comment: @WhozCraig I like making things systematically understandable. That's what I tried to do up there.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Your explanation was really helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TheLearner Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

`int** array` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. So by doing this:

```
int** array = new int*[n];
```

you are creating a section of memory that holds `n` `int*` pointers and pointing `array` at that memory. For each of these pointers that you have created, it is possible to create a set of `int`s like so:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[n];
```

The resulting memory will look like this:

```
array -> [       int*     |     int *     |   .... n
         [int | int | ...][int | int | ...][  ... n
```

This is however, much much easier if you use some of the `std` things in c++, ie a `std::vector` :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(std::vector<int>(0, n), n);
```

and you are done ...

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you for your help.